# Is it possible to modify the zoom transition in Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Have been researching if the zoom transitions between zoom levels could be modified for the Google Maps JS API (Version: 3.16). But have not found anything relevant in this regard.

The current zoom animations are kinda "jerky" and are a little too fast for the current site I am developing. Is it possible to modify the zoom transition between zoom levels? How hard is it to achieve a slower transition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no option in the API to alter the zoom transition speed.

Comment: Yeah I know, have been reading the API reference but not found one thing about this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *jerky* or *too fast*? Did you try it with a decent browser on a decent machine?

Comment: Of course, its actually a project where the map has three stages (three zoom levels based on one's position). The map needs to automatically zoom out after X milliseconds. At the moment I am using the setZoom method on the map, and the transition is standard Google Maps kinda jerky. It would be nice to have the transition more smooth than the standard transition speed, which is a pretty fast transition.

Comment: Well you can't. You can open a new [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype:Javascript3%20type:Enhancement&sort=-stars&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars) in the hope that Google will implement it. Some day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll tell you this. Most transitions are almost an optical illusion. What I'm trying to say is that the API won't give you this kind of tool, but you still can work around it.

You could use an overlay to make your transition.

Comment: My solution was to layer several maps unto each other and after an timer transition them in. Each map had their own zoom level but every map was centered at the same latlang. This created an illusion of a more smooth zoom. Only a solution I would recommend for simple projects. I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thats the question. I probably need to test out some more, its working okay now. But performance could be an issue